# File replace is not working

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project there is a requirement of updating configuration periodically. So i save configuration in xml file and download it. At first it downloads but when i am updating it shows me require admin credential. It doesn't happen earlier but starts now at the time of update.For update configuration i download a new file and replace it from the previous one. But it demands for the admin credential to replace that file.

Comment: Are you closing the xml file once you did read it? Probably it is still open, so you can't replace it

Comment: After reading i close it properly.

Comment: Please show the code. Perhaps you don't close it when you write it to the file after downloading it?

Comment: actually i am using dataset to read xml file so i don't think that i need to close because i am not creating any stream .

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Which part you want to see, because code is so lengthy, So please tell me what you want to see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111600/discussion-between-anoop-mishra-and-andre-schild).

Comment: add manifest file to your project and change access level to requireAdministrator

Comment: To what directory are you saving the downloaded file?